# edit file extension with php

Tags: php, onclick, rename

So, I'm working on an php interface, basically this script should print a list of clients' name, one under the other, where for each row there are 2 buttons, "enable" and "disable".
For each client there is a file.conf, and those buttons next to the names, must activate (leave or put .conf extension to the file) or disable (leave or put .disable extension to the file).

Currently I am able to have the names of the customers printed on screen, with this code:

```
<?php
$var=fopen("Names.txt","r");
while (!feof($var))
{
$row= fgets($var);
echo $row.
"<button type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">Enable</button>
 <button type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">Disable</button>
 <br>";
}
fclose($var);
?>
```

In other codes, i used OnClick buttons with rename() function, it works, but I don't know how to refer this name with this .conf file

Here's an example of "Names.txt" it's in italian

```
nome_cliente001
nome_cliente002
nome_cliente003
nome_cliente004
nome_cliente005
nome_cliente006
nome_cliente007
nome_cliente008
nome_cliente009
nome_cliente010
```

if it is not clear tell me that I try to explain myself better, excuse me in advance

Comment: show us an example of the input file `Names.txt`

Comment: check the post! i put an exemple at the end now :)

Comment: Is this HTML output inside a `<form>`

Comment: could you explain yourself better?

Comment: `onclick` functions run on the client. `rename()` has to run on the server. You either have to submit the form or use AJAX.